# Qt stylesheet used in Qt Creator, AutoCAD, 

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

Is there a stylesheet available for use in Qt applications (through Qt Creator) that makes your GUI use the stylesheet you see in Qt Creator itself, as well as in AutoCAD and some other applications?

What is the name of that stylesheet or where can I get it? It looks much like the Vista stylesheet though...

And whenever you set a custom stylesheet to your Qt application, will it display the same style on all platforms, or will it still display native GUI parts?

Comment: When you set a custom stylesheet, it should be used for almost all of your application on all platforms.  The only places where it would not be used are items created by functions that say something like "this uses the platform's native file select dialog".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say as to how you would get style sheets that match Qt Creator or AutoCAD but to answer your other question: When you apply a style sheet, it applies to the object you applied it to, and the child hierarchy of that object. Any widget not addressed by the style sheet in some way will maintain the native look and feel that matches the Style (not style sheet) chosen by Qt as most appropriate for you application based on the user's platform and desktop environment.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just have to make a similar style myself with the stylesheets. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To the people that may want to find out more: The style seems to be called manhattanstyle and extends QWindowsStyle. It is not a css-stylesheet and therefore not just copy and paste to set up. It seems to have some other dependencies in the source code, so I don't know how much it will take to adapt it.

The source is found in the [qt-creator source code]/src/plugins/coreplugin/manhattanstyle.cpp

And btw: if you are running debian/ubuntu: type apt-get source qt-creator to get the source ;)

Answer (score 2):

yes, somebody has separated it out. 
see this [Manhattan style](https://github.com/tegesoft/qt-manhattan-style)